# Remove any string in HTML files python

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup, editing

I am currently using beautiful soup to auto tag some links in HTML, the sample below shows what I get in return, everything is pretty much fine apart from the fact that "&&" is converted into

```
&amp;&amp;
```

And for whatever reason, the below string of DIVs gets added

```
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

```
return typeof jQuery === 'function' &amp;&amp; 
<div>
'<a href="" title="example">example</a>
</div>

</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

I would like to find a way to remove this, after I have applied the script to tag the links.
I have tried

```
soup.replace("</div></div></div>", '')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

re.sub('&amp;&amp;',"",soup)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I would like something like the below instead

```
return typeof jQuery === 'function' && 
<div>
'<a href="" title="example">example</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `soup` is a list and you are performing string operations on a list which is not allowed.

Comment: Please reduce your program and its input to the shortest possible **complete** versions that demonstrate the problem. Your readers would like to copy-paste those files and reproduce your issue. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: please add more clear example, why soup is a list?,
you can do this re.sub('&amp;&amp;',"",str(soup)), or str(soup).replace("</div></div></div>", '')

Comment: Can you explain "auto tag some links" are you adding new elements or editing existing elements? without seeing your code it is impossible to know where you are going wrong.

Comment: @Dan-Dev in the context of running an AB test, we are adding about 200 links to a navigation menu. The javascript developer I work with is building the structure of the menu, while I writing a script that will populate the title tag, html text, href and so on. The information is coming from a csv file . This bit I v got working, however beautiful soup tends to encode some of the tags (&) so I have got to find a way to revert them to what they were originally. regarding the extra DIVs, Ihave now idea why BS does that

Comment: is this code in a "script" element? can you at least show more of the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got much to go on without the full code but my guess is that you are missing script tags.

If you add the JavaScript to a script element it is not HTML encoded you get what you expect i.e. the &&.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

body = """
<html><body><div><a href="" title="example"></a></div></body></html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(body, "lxml")
original_tag = soup.find("div")
new_tag = soup.new_tag("script")
new_tag.string = "return typeof jQuery === 'function' && <div>'"
original_tag.insert(0, new_tag)
print (soup)
```

Outputs:

```
<html><body><div><script>return typeof jQuery === 'function' && <div>'</script><a href="" title="example"></a></div></body></html>
```

Where as if you add the JavaScript to the wrong element e.g. a div it doesn't work as expected you get

```
&amp;&amp;.
```

This doesn't work as expected.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

body = """
<html><body><div><a href="" title="example"></a></div></body></html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(body, "lxml")
original_tag = soup.find("div")
new_tag = soup.new_tag("div")
new_tag.string = "return typeof jQuery === 'function' && <div>'"
original_tag.insert(0, new_tag)
print (soup)
```

Outputs:

```
<html><body><div><div>return typeof jQuery === 'function' &amp;&amp; &lt;div&gt;'</div><a href="" title="example"></a></div></body></html>
```

The JavaScript in you example needs to be in a script element or it will not work and my guess is that it is not because you are getting the &s HTML encoded. If your JavaScript is outside script tags it is just text not code and won't work.

The extra closing div tags may well come from the same error.